# Deploying Ember application with Addon to Github Pages

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, github-pages, ember-addon

My organization is using Ember addons to develop a set of shared components between our applications.  Let's call this repository `app-components`.  Currently the components application's primary responsibility is to distribute CSS, fonts and images.

We are also building a living styleguide that will ingest our shared components and present them in a neutral way for developers to reference.  Let's call this repository `app-styleguide`.  Our goal is to deploy `app-styleguide` using `ember-deploy` to deploy this solution to Github Pages.  The url follows this pattern:

https://organization.github.io/app-styleguide/

When the `app-styleguide` application makes it to the `gh-pages` branch and is served as a webpage, all of the fonts and images being delivered by `app-components` are giving us a 404. I have referenced a handful of different solutions to this problem, but I keep coming across the same solutions that we have tried.

I have tried using the following two ember addons that automate the deploy to github pages:

1. https://github.com/poetic/ember-cli-github-pages
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-deploy-gh-pages

In the end we went with a vanilla [ember-cli-deploy](http://ember-cli-deploy.com/) solution, as those two addons are quite old...

I have followed the instructions here to add `rootUrl and`locationType`properties to our`environment.js` file, which has not worked:

- https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/398

Our environment.js file looks like this:

```
if (environment === 'production') {
    ENV.rootURL = '/app-styleguide';
    ENV.locationType = 'hash';
  }
```

And our requests continue to not add `app-styleguide` to the request URL's for assets coming from the Addon.  Here is an example of a failed request from the Chrome DevTools Network tab:

```
Request URL:https://organization.github.io/assets/images/thumbnail-icons/person.svg
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

As you can see, `app-styleguide` is not added to the request.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where do you reference the `person.svg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to receive some help over on the [Ember Slack Community](http://embercommunity.slack.com)
 (special thanks to @alexspeller).  It turns out I needed to update a couple of settings in the fingerprinting of assets.

Using the included `broccoli-asset-rev` library I had to modify my `ember-cli-build.js` to include the following:

```
var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    fingerprint: {
      extensions: ['js', 'css', 'png', 'jpg', 'gif', 'map', 'svg', 'ttf', 'woff'],
      prepend: '/app-styleguide/'
    }
  });
```

I needed to update the options to account for SVG, TTF, & WOFF, as well as the proper prepended url segment.

You can read about the functionality here:
https://ember-cli.com/asset-compilation#fingerprinting-and-cdn-urls

Available options:
https://github.com/cibernox/broccoli-asset-rev?files=1#options